# How to give number in order even if I delete a row of inputs the order should not be duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the length property from jquery for numbering but the order is missed once I delete a row. Duplicate numbers exist againg

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight">' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="a"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></a><input type="button" class="form-control Minus" value="delete" /></div>');
  x.appendTo('#form .con')
});

$('.con').on('click', '.Minus', function() {
  $(this).parents(".ui-state-highlight").remove();
});

$("span").sortable({
  connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="add">add another option</button>
    <form id="form" class="form-inline">
      <span class="con">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="button" class="Minus" value="-" />
        </div>
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you wish to renumber your "order" number when things change?

With a slight update to your markup (add a span around the number) and then some minor changes this can be done.

First I got rid of the large string you append and simply cloned the first row and clear the inputs
I then prevented that first row from being removed IF it is the only row.

I added a `rowid` class to make it easier to do this.

I then updated that number for all rows when anything changes, including a sort.

Markup with changes:

```
<div>
    <button id="add">add another option</button>
    <form id="form" class="form-inline"> <span class="con">
        <div class="row ui-state-highlight"><span class="rowid">1</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="button" class="Minus" value="-" />
        </div></span>
    </form>
</div>

function fixIds() {
    $('#form .con').find('.rowid').each(function (i) {
        $(this).text(i + 1);
    });
}
$('#add').click(function () {
    var x = $('#form').find('.row:first').clone();
    x.find('.form-control').val('');
    x.appendTo('#form .con');
    fixIds();
});
$('.con').on('click', '.Minus', function () {
    if ($('.rowid').length > 1) {
        $(this).parents(".ui-state-highlight").remove();
        fixIds();
    }
});
$("span.con").sortable({
    connectWith: ".con"
}); //.disableSelection();
$("span.con").on("sortupdate", function (event, ui) {
    fixIds();
});
```

Fiddle to play with: `http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/wLum04bq/`

Comment: Thank you so Much @ mark Schulthesis. Is there any site or do you suggest any books for learning Jquery and javascript. I'm new and trying to learn it by myself. Thank you @Mark Once again.

Comment: You can start a number of ways, JavaScript is the basis for jQuery  - study the JavaScript first, then understand what jQuery is doing within that  Look at the questions here and the answers and understand what they are doing etc..  At the intermediate level consider: http://www.amazon.com/Secrets-JavaScript-Ninja-John-Resig/dp/193398869X

Answer (score 0):

You are using AngularJS.  The best possible option is to have that as an ng-repeat.  Going outside of Angular is a bad idea and will cause many problems in the future.  Would have put this is a comment but apparently not allowed.

/edit

...are you using Angular? you do not include it, but you have ng-model attribute?

Comment: Fill out your profile some more then change it to a comment